How can I deep link to UPI Payment apps and pay without being a merchant?
I am trying to initiate a UPI payment from my Jetpack Compose app. To create the intent string, I tried this method.
fun getUPIString(
    payeeAddress: String,
    payeeName: String,
    trxnNote: String,
    payeeAmount: String,
    transactionId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    transactionRefId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
): String {
    val UPI = ("upi://pay?pa=$payeeAddress&pn=${payeeName}&tn=$trxnNote&am=$payeeAmount&tid=$transactionId&tr=$transactionRefId&cu=INR")
    return UPI.replace(" ", "+")
}

I tried both PhonePe and GPay, both open with the correct data, both failed.
"Your payment is declined due to security reasons. Please try using a mobile number, UPI ID, or QR Code."
I am not a merchant and being a merchant is not a viable option for my app since it is intended to pay to friends. If it is not possible, please refer me to the documentation.

There are no options to do this because of RBI regulations. You should integrate any payment gateway.

Can you please link me to the regulations page? @Pisumathu
